# Rails: dependent: :destroy deletes record even after reassignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, belongs-to, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 app where users can sign up as guest `User`s to try out my service. Each `User` (and guest user) can have many `App`s. The relationship looks like this:

```
# User.rb
has_many :apps, dependent: :destroy

# App.rb
belongs_to :user
```

When a guest user decides to sign up to the service I want to:

- (1) Reassign the guest user's app(s) to the new current user.
- (2) Delete the old guest user (without deleting the app).

The problem I'm having is that the app gets deleted even if I reassign the `app.user` to my new `current_user` (I use the Device gem), before deleting the old guest user.

In my `class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` I override the `create` action like this (the relevant parts):

```
# POST /resource
def create
  user_params = params[:user]
  new_user_from_guest = guest_user
  build_resource(sign_up_params)
  resource.save
  yield resource if block_given?
  if resource.persisted?
    if resource.active_for_authentication?
      set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
      sign_up(resource_name, resource)

      # Reassigns the app
      reasign_app_for_user(new_user_from_guest)

      Mailer.deliver_welcome_message(current_user).deliver_later!
      respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)

      # delete the guest user (this also deletes the app)
      delete_guest_user!
    else
      [...]
    end
  else
    [...]
  end
end

# ... my private methods for deleting the current user and reassigning the app's owner.
def reasign_app_for_user(user)
  user.apps.each do |app|
    app.user = current_user
    app.save!
  end
end

# ... this method deletes the app, even if it is called after the reassign method.
def delete_guest_user!
  guest_user(with_retry = false).try(:destroy)
  session[:guest_user_id] = nil
end
```

Any ideas on why this is happening or what I'm doing wrong?

**Update**

This is how my `user_params` variable look like after submit:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"Test user", "email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"testing"} permitted: false>
```

And this is how `sign_up_params` look:

```
{"email"=>"test@example.com", "password"=>"testing", "name"=>"Test"}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `guest_user` and `current_user` are not the same?

Comment: Can you show us `sign_up_params` and `params[:user]`?

Comment: when you use save! that silences errors. Try removing the exclamation mark. Also helpful to place breakpoints in your code. Debugging will never be the seem once you learn this.

Comment: @Aleksey Yes, they are not the same.

Comment: @SergiiK I have added it to my original question.

Comment: @maxpleaner Thanks! I have tried both with and without `!` without success. I use the gem `byebug` for debugging, but can't figure this one out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider duplicating the apps before assigning them to the new user. This way, there's no confusion about if it's the same app or not.

```
guest.apps.each do |app|
  current_user.apps << app.dup
end
```

Simply like this. The shovel operator ensures that the new, duplicated app is saved to the `current_user` object.

Or even simpler and more compact:

```
current_user.apps = guest.apps.map(&:dup)
current_user.save
```